# Can't install rake on Mac OS X: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I'm having the worst time trying to install rake. Every time I start rake I get "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass". I hear solutions exist, such as installing older versions of rubygems, but to do so I can't use macports and life starts sucking again.

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9]
- gem 1.3.7
- rake, version 0.8.7

All installed with macports.

Any suggestions? I've been putting apt-get and macports up against each other in different fights, but that didn't work out, so now I'm putting all my money on macports.

Oh, I am on Mac OS X Leopard (10.5).

And the trace starts with:

- /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in `activate'
- /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
- /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
- /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
- /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
- ...

Comment: Interesting detail: the app requires rails 2.3, whereas I have rails 3.0 installed. A newly created 3.0 app works fine.

Comment: Alright, that does it, I quit, I'll virtualbox my way out of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead of macports? It's a package manager that works with OS X 10.5 or later. I've been using it in conjunction with [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to handle various Rubies and gemsets and it's worked out great.

Comment: as ruralocity say, install RVM  Especially if you are developing in multiple versions of libraries.  The per project gemset of RVM works wonders..

Comment: homebrew + rvm + bundler = awesomeness!

Comment: It appears my problem is related to some other version related issue, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out. Will get back once I do.